# calling jQuery from td

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have created a table with a row and 4 columns.i declared attributes class,id for td element. when i click on the td i have to call the jQuery function to load pop up box. here instead load pop up i just want to display the alert box but it doesn't work. here is my code

jQuery

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(e) {
                alert("jquery");
                $('.tbox').click(function(e) {
            tb_show("ThickBox","hi.html?height=120&width=400","true");  
            }
    });

</script>
```

html code:

```
<table>
<tr align="center">
<td class="tbox" id="tbox"> <?=$id?> </td>
<td class="tbox" id="tbox"><?=$zoneName?></td>
</tr></table>
```

how to call the jQuery?

Comment: Use firebug to see errors reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $('.tbox').click(function (e) {
    alert("jquery");
  });
});
```

is this what you were asking?

Comment: But it will create same alert at every div with that class name

Comment: ya i did mistake . Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

Your event handler has not been closed properly, causing a parse error. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    alert("jquery");
    $('.tbox').click(function(e) {
        tb_show("ThickBox", "hi.html?height=120&width=400", "true");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using two divs with same id. Thats why I think its not working. Trying varying the name of the divs and they will work fine

```
$('document').ready(function(){

   $('#tbox1').click(function(){
     alert("I am from div1");
   });

 $('#tbox2').click(function(){
     alert("I am from div2");
   });
});
```

Comment: He uses the class selector (.tbox), not the id selector (#tbox) so it should work

Comment: @Prashanth: Though using same id might be semantically incorrect, that wouldn't be an issue here as OP is using .tbox (class) selector.

Comment: @Riash try the code i suggested if u wanna assign different tasks to different td